# R sessionInfo() differs from Visual Studio Code and RStudio

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, rstudio

I'm new at R in VSCode. I realised that some terminal commands don't run in VSCode but in RStudio. I looked at the session information in both and this is what I got:

**VSCode**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Big Sur ... 10.16
```

**RStudio**

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.2.1 (2022-06-23)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin17.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS Monterey 12.5.1
```

My current macOS version is `macOS Monterey 12.5.1`. Why R in VSCode is running under a different macOS version? Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: What happens if you open a plain R terminal (not VS Code or RStudio) and run `sessionInfo()` in that?

Comment: I'm wondering if VSCode is installed in a different drive partition that's using a different OS. If so, try reinstalling VSCode in the same partition as where RStudio is installed.